# Quando rodo meu WCF REST entra a tela de WCF Client Test

Tags: web-service, rest, wcf

Quando rodo meu WCF REST entra a tela de WCF Client Test. Antes estava funcionando. Porque isso está acontecendo, ou seja, porque entra a tela de WCF Client Test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque você está rodando a partir do seu arquivo `.svc`. Rode a partir de qualquer outro arquivo para conseguir debug em browser.

Em suma: se você executar (com debug ou não) estando no arquivo `.svc`, a janela WCF Test Client é exibida. Note que o arquivo `.svc` quando aberto apresenta extensão `.svc.cs` na lista de abas abertas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show de bola, obrigado.